# How to set subtitle in UINavigationController's title?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In some app I liked the title with two different lines of text:

[image]

How can I do this?

So far I used `self.title = "My Title"`.

I know about **Prompt**, but it is not that.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done automatically through the Storyboard. Just create apriopriate `titleView` as an `UIView` and then assign it to titleView property.

```
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```